# Russell's Paradox

Tags: math, paradox, set-theory

Let X be the set of all sets that do not contain themselves. Is X a member of X?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **ZFC**, either the axiom of foundation [as mentioned] or the axiom (scheme) of comprehension will prohibit this. The first, for obvious reasons; the second, since it basically says that for given *z* and first-order property *P*, you can construct { *x* ∈ *z* : *P*(*x*) }, but to generate the Russell set, you would need *z* = *V* (the class of all sets), which is not a set (i.e. cannot be generated from any of the given axioms).

In New Foundations (**NF**), "*x* ∉ *x*" is not a stratified formula, and so again we cannot define the Russell set. Somewhat amusingly, however, *V* *is* a set in **NF**.

In von Neumann--Bernays--Gödel set theory (**NBG**), the class *R* = { *x* : *x* is a set and *x* ∉ *x* } is definable. We then ask whether *R* ∈ *R*; if so, then also *R* ∉ *R*, giving a contradiction. Thus we must have *R* ∉ *R*. But there is no contradiction here, since for any given class *A*, *A* ∉ *R* implies either *A* ∈ *A* or *A* is a proper class. Since *R* ∉ *R*, we must simply have that *R* is a proper class.

Of course, the class *R* = { *x* : *x* ∉ *x* }, without the restriction, is simply not definable in **NBG**.

Also of note is that the above procedure is formally constructable as a proof in **NBG**, whereas in **ZFC** one has to resort to meta-reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

The question is ill-posed in the standard [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo-Fraenkel_set_theory) (Zermelo-Fraenkel + axiom of Choice) set theory because the object thus defined is not a set.

Since (again, assuming standard ZFC) your *class* {x : x\not\in x} is not a set, the answer becomes no, it's not an element of itself (even as a class) since only sets can be elements of classes or sets.

By the way, as soon as you agree to the [axiom of foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_foundation), no set can be an element of itself.

Of course the nice thing about math is you can choose whichever axioms you want :) but believing in paradoxes is just weird.

Comment: But ZFC says nothing about classes, it only defines what are sets.

Comment: Yes, ZFC says nothing about classes.  So you could try to re-state the paradox for classes, but ZFC sidesteps that by only allowing the concept of "is a member of" to be defined for sets.  So, still, the question is "X a member of X?" can't be stated within the language of ZFC, since X is not a set, and the phrase "a member of" is not defined for non-sets.

The goal of math is not to make sense of self-contradictions like "this sentence is false," but rather to explore consistent systems of thought.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant proof I've ever seen resembles Russell's paradox closely.

**Theorem** (Cantor, I suppose).
Let X be a set, and 2^X the set of its subsets. Then card(X) < card(2^X).

**Proof**. Surely card(X) <= card(2^X), since there is a trivial bijection between X and the singletons in 2^X. We must prove that card(X) != card(2^X).

Suppose there is a bijection between X and 2^X. Then each xk in X is mapped to a set Ak in 2^X.

- x1 ---> A1
- x2 ---> A2
- ...
- xk ---> Ak
- ...

For each xk the chances are: either xk belongs to Ak, or it does not. Let M be the set of all those xk that do *not* belong to their corresponding set Ak. M is a subset of X, thus there must exist an element m of X which is mapped to M by the bijection.

Does m belong to M? If it does, then it does not, for M is the set of those x that do *not* belong to the set they're mapped to. If it does not, then it does, for M contains *all* such x's. This contradiction stems from the assumption that a bijection exists. Thus a bijection cannot exist, the two cardinalities are different, and the theorem is proved.